# Leaflet printing does not show pins and map is shifted

Tags: javascript, leaflet, printing

I don't exactly why but whenever I try to print my leaflet map with layers, it shows the map a little shifted to the left as well as the pins are not quite ok. I tried using `easyPrint()` and `window.print()`, same result. It used to work well. Any ideas? Here is the difference

[image: how it should look]

when it opens up to print the map
[image: how it looks]

Comment: Did you try print() for the map div container ?  $('#map').print();

Comment: Can you post your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222058/leaflet-easyprint-plugin-only-prints-left-half-of-screen?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried either of the printing solutions listed here?

http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport