# Leaflet EasyPrint plugin only prints left half of screen

Tags: leaflet, printing

I'm trying to print maps from my Leaflet app using the [Leaflet EasyPrint](https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint). Installation is easy, I made it run but it only prints the left half of the screen, not the entire window.

I see that one can only configure: title, position of button and select the html elements to hide.

Does anyone have experience with the EasyPrint plugin and can advise how to configure it to print the entire screen?

Comment: Funnily enough I ran into the exact same problem, a day after you. If you step through the code, the `leaflet.easyPrint.js` script is essentially just calling `window.print();` so you can emulate this behaviour independently of the plugin. I note that there is an unresolved [issue](https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint/issues/10) on the plugin to address this

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks a ton for the reply! I'll check the issue and try to work with window.print() to make it fit. Did you manage to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Nope, I've given up for now. It looks like printing what's on the page, at the correct scale and size, is pretty complicated ;)